# Hover effect on svg image doesn't works on pages linked with Single Articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jquery

I have **social icons** in the **Footer** of my site and those **images are in svg format**.

Now `I need to change my images on hovering`.

I have applied the following jquery, which **works fine on the home page**. But **it doesn't works on the menu's that has Menu Type as *Single Article***.

The jquery is and I've placed it in my template's index file :

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var sourcehover = function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var hoverimg = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', hoverimg);
    };
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
            new Image().src = jQuery(this).data('alt-src'); 
        }).hover(sourcehover); 
    });
    });
</script>
```

The html for the footer icons is here :

```
    <div class="social clearfix"> 
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/social-icons/fb.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/fb_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/google-plus.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/googleplus_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/youtube.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/youtube_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/pinterest.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/pinterest_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/instagram_hover.svg" />
</a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/twitter_hover.svg" />
    </a>

  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/linkedin.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/linkedin_hover.svg" />
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please check your browser console for any JS errors

Comment: Yes, the image links links changes and that menu is added in the url. For which it says 404 image not found

Comment: Like if current image is at `localhost/test/images/fb_hover.svg` on inner pages it changes to  `localhost/test/page1/images/fb_hover.svg`

Answer (score 2):

Can you make it using css? `a:hover { ...`

But if you prefer JQuery:

```
<div class="social clearfix"> 
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="/images/social-icons/f1.svg" alt="always_add_alt_except_for_decoration_purposes" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="/images/social-icons/f2.svg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

JS code is the same.

It is working perfectly well even with single article view. It is possible your troubles to be linked with localhost server. `images` is the standard Joomla folder.

Comment: Nopes, as I want to do it using js

Comment: OK, but could you explain a bit more - HTML is in custom HTML module or directly in template index file? What template are you using? Could you provide live demo?

Comment: Using **Protostar template with bootstrap**, and yes it is **custom HTML module**.
_But, I have added the js in the template's index file only._

Comment: @Nehal: I tested your js code with the html in my answer and it works well. Note leading slash in url. Try it on non-windows environment.

Comment: This can be a issue, as I'm checking it on windows system only. and currently I'm not even having any non-windows environment.
But I'll check it for sure if it is the issue.

Comment: You can make demo [here](https://demo.joomla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes to your code. The main one being using `JUri::root` as the root of your path

**HTML:**

```
<div class="social clearfix"> 
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/social-icons/fb.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/fb_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/google-plus.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/googleplus_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/youtube.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/youtube_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/pinterest.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/pinterest_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/instagram.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/instagram_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/twitter.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/twitter_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/linkedin.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="images/social-icons/linkedin_hover.svg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var sourcehover = function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var hoverimg = $this.data('alt-src');
            $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
            $this.attr('src', hoverimg);
        };
        $(function() {
            $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
                new Image().src = '<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>' + $(this).data('alt-src'); 
            }).hover(sourcehover); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think so that I need to add `<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>` to the **img src** as I have created custom HTML module for it.

And **adding** the  `<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>` to the _script_ also **doesn't affects** the hovering issue.

Comment: Ahh it's a custom HTML module, in that case PHP won't work unless you use a third party extensions such as [Sourcerer](www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer). You do need to add `<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>` because this defined the root path of your site, so even if you're URL is `localhost/test/page1`, it will always return `localhost/test`. By not defining a proper path, it will take the default URL that your browser is currently on

Comment: **so even if you're URL is `localhost/test/page1`, it will always return `localhost/test`**.

This is what I want, if it always returns the base url my work is done.

Comment: Yes, this is what you need, therefore you must use `<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>`

Comment: I added that in the script but it didn't work. **It works fine for the rest menu's like rsform, articles category and the rest**.
_**It only creates issues with Single Article Menu Type.**_

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the same effect using pure CSS. Take a look at this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="social clearfix"> 
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="googleplus"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="youtube"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="pinterest"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="instagram"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="linkedin"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.social a {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 32px;
    height:32px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.social a.facebook{background-image:url('path/to/fb.svg');}
.social a.facebook:hover{background-image:url('path/to/fb_hover.svg');}

.social a.googleplus{background-image:url('path/to/googleplus.svg');}
.social a.googleplus:hover{background-image:url('path/to/googleplus_hover.svg');}

.social a.youtube{background-image:url('path/to/youtube.svg');}
.social a.youtube:hover{background-image:url('path/to/youtube_hover.svg');}

.social a.pinterest{background-image:url('path/to/pinterest.svg');}
.social a.pinterest:hover{background-image:url('path/to/pinterest_hover.svg');}

.social a.instagram{background-image:url('path/to/instagram.svg');}
.social a.instagram:hover{background-image:url('path/to/instagram_hover.svg');}

.social a.twitter{background-image:url('path/to/twitter.svg');}
.social a.twitter:hover{background-image:url('path/to/twitter_hover.svg');}

.social a.linkedin{background-image:url('path/to/linkedin.svg');}
.social a.linkedin:hover{background-image:url('path/to/linkedin_hover.svg');}
```

That should work, as long as you add the correct path to your images (replace `path/to/` with the actual path *relative* to your css file.

**Here's a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06Lr9L3m/).**

Comment: This might be the solution but I want it to be done using js

Comment: Sorry to say, but this css also didn't work.

Comment: @Nehal You probably have the relative path wrong, that is probably hardest thing with css...

Comment: there is a typo in googleplus hover, I can't edit it myself since it is less than 6 characters...

Comment: @Nehal make sure you have the right path, I've added a quick JSFiddle to the answer to show you the idea. But if you want to use js, @Lodders answer is the solution (or use absolute paths beginning with `/` or `http://`.

Comment: @VilleNiemi, thanks for noticing, I've fixed it :)

Comment: @johanpw If you have changed something in your code, then I should try it.
Because `path of the image was definitely not an an issue`. As I was able to see the image, only issue was that the `css wasn't correct`.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do something with javascript that can easily be done with just ccs?? You *want* a heavier, slower and fragile .js solution to a fast, lightweight and robust css solution that works on any device…

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would a) use two images for each icon, or b) use javascript. You can define hover states, and manipulate svg elements directly, with only the most elementary css, e.g;

```
<img class="icon-instagram" src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>images/instagram.svg" alt="" />

.icon-instagram:hover path {fill: #bada55;}
```